# A simple web server to consume a POST request - Server hangs after one or two requests

Tags: c#, http, tcp, tcplistener

I am building a small windows application to consume a POST request. The code below works fine for GET requests and for the first POST request. Basically when I read the POST DATA it works fine the first time (or the first few times). After a while (a few seconds - it hangs. Any incoming request hangs. Any ideas? Assume the content length is correct.

```
            while (true)
            {

                System.Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");
                System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

                TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                int incomingDataLength = client.ReceiveBufferSize;
                Stream ist = client.GetStream();

                BufferedStream bst = new BufferedStream(ist);

                int k = 0;

                String line = ReadLine(bst);
                System.Console.WriteLine(line);

                while ((line = ReadLine(bst)) != null)
                {
                    if (line == "") break;
                    System.Console.WriteLine(line);
                }

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                int contentLen = 3429;
                //if (this.HttpHeaders.ContainsKey("Content-Length"))
                {
                    //content_len = Convert.ToInt32(this.HttpHeaders["Content-Length"]);
                    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                    int to_read = content_len;
                    while (to_read > 0)
                    {
                        int numread = bst.Read(buf, 0, Math.Min(buf.Length, to_read));
                        if (numread == 0)
                        {
                            if (to_read == 0) break;
                            else throw new Exception("client disconnected during post");
                        }
                        to_read -= numread;
                        ms.Write(buf, 0, numread);
                    }
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
                }

                bst.Close();
                client.Close();
```

And the ReadLine is

```
private String ReadLine(Stream stream)
{
    int k;
    StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while (true)
    {
        k = stream.ReadByte();
        if (k < 0) continue;

        char c = Convert.ToChar(k);
        if (c == '\n') break;
        if (c == '\r') continue;

        lineBuilder.Append(c);
    }

    return lineBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is `ReadLine`? Where does it hang when you pause the debugger? Use `using` blocks for bst and client.

Comment: Dont worry about the using blocks. They are not relevant. A million things can be better about this code but I m interested on why it blocks.

Comment: It blocks in the ReadLine

Comment: Can't repro. http://postimg.org/image/7tqcsth3z/ What am I missing? What did you not include? What is your test client? Looks like it is not sending any more data. It's broken.

Comment: Test client is the Advanced REST client (Chrome extension). Try to run a POST request. Wait for a couple of minutes and run it again.

Comment: GET requests are fine (per original desc)

Comment: Ok I can reproduce this now with a simple GET from IE10. Chance that it happens seems to be about 1/4. Here's a full repro: http://pastebin.com/MN4cgmRw it should output "read 1234" but it often just hangs without a single byte being read. I don't know how to further simplify this... What could possibly be the reason for this? Network reads are supposed to return only the bytes available (if there is at least one). They do not fill an entire buffer AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Yannis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133405/yannis) suggested, you may not be disposing your objects, especially your streams. `Using` statements, like you did with the StreamReader, will automatically do this for you. For example:

```
  while (true)
  {

  System.Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");
  System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

  using (TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient())
  {
        int incomingDataLength = client.ReceiveBufferSize;

        using (Stream ist = client.GetStream())
        {
              //Stream ist = client.GetStream();
              using (BufferedStream bst = new BufferedStream(ist))
              {
                     //BufferedStream bst = new BufferedStream(ist);

                     int k = 0;

                     String line = ReadLine(bst);
                     System.Console.WriteLine(line);

                      while ((line = ReadLine(bst)) != null)
                      {
                            if (line == "") break;
                            System.Console.WriteLine(line);
                      }

                      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                      {
                            //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            int contentLen = 3429;
                            if (this.HttpHeaders.ContainsKey("Content-Length"))
                            {
                                  //content_len = Convert.ToInt32(this.HttpHeaders["Content-Length"]);
                                  byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                                  int to_read = content_len;
                                  while (to_read > 0)
                                  {
                                         int numread = bst.Read(buf, 0, Math.Min(buf.Length, to_read));
                                         if (numread == 0)
                                         {
                                               if (to_read == 0) break;
                                              else throw new Exception("client disconnected during post");
                                         }
                                         to_read -= numread;
                                         ms.Write(buf, 0, numread);
                                   }
                                   ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                             }

                       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                       {
                             System.Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
                       }

                       //bst.Close();
                       client.Close();
                 } //end memorystream
              } //end bufferedsteam
          } //end stream
      } //end tcpClient
  } //end while
```